# Checking if XML have some elements

Tags: python, xml, loops, for-loop, if-statement

For example I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

How can I check (in Python) if Lichtenstein have neighbor Austria and get the direction?
And I want also check (with no errors) if Lichtenstein have maybe another neighbor, for example Germany?

In a nutshell I want to check if country have a specified (by me) neighbor and if it exist, what is the direction. **If country don't have specified neighbor**, the direction should be set to '' (empty).

I tried with code:

```
for Country in data.iter('Country'):
  cntr = Country.get('name')  
  if cntr == 'Lichtenstein':
    if 'Austria' in neighbor.attrib:
       austr_dir = neighbor.get('direction')
    else:
       austr_dir = ''
    if 'Germany' in neighbor.attrib:
       germ_dir = neighbor.get('direction')
    else:
       germ_dir = ''
```

and:

```
for Country in data.iter('Country'):
  cntr = Country.get('name')  
  if cntr == 'Lichtenstein':
    for neighbor in cntr.iter('neighbor'):
        nghbr_name = neighbor.get('name') 
        if nghbr_name == 'Austria':
          austr_dir = neighbor.get('direction')
        if nghbr_name == 'Germany':
          germ_dir = neighbor.get('direction')
```

Then I want to put it all into a data frame.
Maybe some other loop? Every time I try some code I have errors like "name 'germ_dir' is not defined", because this XML dont have Germany neighbor or I dont have propper values of directions.

Maybe someone would have better idea.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use `beautifulsoup` to parse the XML?

Comment: Xpath could help `//country[@name="Lichtenstein"]/neighbor[@name="Austria"]/@direction`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the dataframe part, but the general direction would be something like this:

```
from lxml import etree
countries = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(countries)
target= "Liechtenstein" #or whatever other country you specify
neighbors = ["Austria","Germany"] #same here
info = doc.xpath(f'//country[@name="{target}"]')[0]


for neighbor in neighbors:
    row = []
    target2 = info.xpath(f'//neighbor[@name="{neighbor}"]/@direction')
    row.extend( target2 if len(target2)>0 else "0" )
    print(neighbor,row[0])
```

Output:

```
Austria E
Germany 0
```